# Knapsack Problem (Problema de mochila) SQL SERVER CTE RECURSIVO

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, recursão

Boa tarde.

Estou tentando desenvolver uma solução dentro do ERP da empresa em que trabalho, com o objetivo de identificar as possibilidades de FATURAS somadas cujo TOTAL seja igual ou aproximado de um valor depositado em conta.

Se eu faço o select com um TOTAL menor, eu encontro as possibilidades de forma bem rápida. Quando tendo fazer com uma situação real, onde o valor pago é bem maior do que o testado, o select fica rodando por horas sem resultado.

Alguém poderia me sugerir uma outra abordagem que seja mais eficiente em tempo de execução?

```
with
SomaFaturas (LastHANDLE, SEQ, SOMA) as 
(select HANDLE as LastHANDLE, ''+CAST(HANDLE AS nvarchar(MAX)) AS SEQ, 
CAST(VALOR AS real) AS SOMA
from k_testefaturas
UNION ALL
SELECT f.HANDLE AS LASTHANDLE, S.SEQ+'-'+CAST(HANDLE AS nvarchar(MAX)) AS SEQ, F.VALOR+S.SOMA AS SOMA
FROM k_testefaturas F
INNER JOIN SomaFaturas S
ON F.HANDLE > S.LASTHANDLE and F.VALOR+S.SOMA<74540.81+0.10)
SELECT SEQ, CAST(SOMA AS numeric(18,2)) AS SOMA FROM SomaFaturas
WHERE SOMA BETWEEN 74540.81-0.10 AND 74540.81+0.10
ORDER BY SEQ
```

A tabela k_testefatura, contem 76 faturas de diversos valores. A mesma esta devidamente indexada com o intuito de melhorar a performance.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui um exemplo do mesmo select, mas com um TOTAL menor a ser encontrado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Knapsack é tão complicado que existem algoritmos de criptografia baseado nisto , fora de uso mas foi pensado.

Comment: @MateusFernandes: Você poderia criar no SQL Fiddle modelo com a estrutura e dados de testes? Isto facilita os testes de possíveis sugestões.

Comment: @JoséDiz, criei lá no Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9cd01/3