# Select com SUM ate que soma B seja igual ou menor que A

Tags: sql, sql-select, stored-procedures

Tenho duas tabelas, produtos e lotes:

**Produtos**

```
codigo
qtdatual
```

**Lotes**

```
codigo
qtdlote
validade
```

Um `select` exemplo seria:

```
SELECT P.CODIGO, L.QTDLOTE, L.VALIDADE
FROM LOTES L
INNER JOIN PRODUTOS P ON(P.CODIGO = L.CODIGO)
WHERE (P.QTDATUAL >= (SELECT SUM(QTDLOTE) FROM LOTES WHERE (CODIGO = P.CODIGO) ORDER BY VALIDADE))
```

No exemplo acima estou tentando trazer somente o lotes que na sua soma são menor ou igual a quantidade atual em estoque, ou seja mesmo que a soma total em lotes fosse maior que a quantidade de produtos eu gostaria de trazem apenas/ate os lotes que entrariam na soma sem ultrapassar a `qtdatual`.

Exemplo literal

**Produtos:**

```
codigo: 1 qtdatual: 30
```

**Lotes:**

```
1: codigo: 1 qtdlote: 10 validade: 01/2018
2: codigo: 1 qtdlote: 15 validade: 02/2018
3: codigo: 1 qtdlote: 20 validade: 03/2017
```

No select eu gostaria de trazer os lotes 1 e 3 (observe a pegadinha na data) que na soma é igual a QTDATUAL de produtos, mas o SUM não trara nenhum lote porque a soma total é maior que produtos.

Será que vou ter que fazer uma procedure pra isso?

ps.: Eu vou fazer um adendo aqui porque depois de olhar e pensar mais nessa pergunta, eu acabei invertendo o caso da validade, mas o select poderá se basear na mesma resposta dos exemplos acima, na verdade eu teria que trazer os lotes mais novos, considerando que os antigos já foram vendidos, então eu traria os lotes 1 e 2, mas aí seria questão de adicionar o DESC na validade, não vai mudar a questão.

Comment: O maior problema é que você não pode considerar as ordens, concorda comigo? Aí qual seria o parâmetro de escolha de quais registros serão selecionados?

Comment: É no exemplo que dei não funciona mesmo, mas a ideia é considerar as validades que são ponto chave nessa consulta, não sei se o HAVING ajudaria nessa questão, estou estudando, a unica solução que vejo seria o uso de procedure com loop nos registros pra fazer as somas.

Comment: Mas que que a validade tem a ver se você não tem com o que comparar?

Comment: No controle de lotes precisamo saber quais lotes já estão vencidos, desta forma temos que trazer primeiro os lotes mais antigos por isso no exemplo coloquei propositalmente o lote 3 mais velho que o 2. Nesta pesquisa temos (e precisamos) o que comparar, a soma dos lotes é comparada ao estoque atual levando em conta os lotes mais antigos pela validade.

Comment: Se você deseja a **maior** soma tal que ela seja menor ou igual que A creio que caia no problema da mochila (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Não sei se deseja tal complexidade. Veja esta questão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/280985/knapsack-problem-problema-de-mochila-sql-server-cte-recursivo

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma solução possível para o seu problema.

```
;WITH CTE AS
( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY validade DESC) AS idRowNumber
       , codigo
       , qtdlote
       , validade
    FROM Lotes
)
, CTE_Recursivo as
( SELECT idRowNumber
       , codigo
       , qtdlote
       , validade
       , vlSoma = qtdlote 
    FROM CTE
   WHERE idRowNumber = 1

   UNION ALL

  SELECT A.idRowNumber
       , A.codigo
       , A.qtdlote
       , A.validade
       , vlSoma = A.qtdlote + B.vlSoma
    FROM CTE A
         INNER JOIN CTE_Recursivo B On A.idRowNumber = B.idRowNumber +1
)
SELECT *
  FROM CTE_Recursivo
 WHERE vlSoma <= (SELECT TOP(1) qtdatual FROM Produtos WHERE Produtos.codigo = CTE_Recursivo.codigo)
```